# How to create following pattern progressbar

Tags: android, progress

i have in some confusion about how to create following type of progress bar, any one can help me to draw following image type progress bar. ?? thanks  in advance.
my image is following of progressbar.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: i know to used for (ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL) but it not gove above image style, i want progress as above image, that give default green horizontal progress bar

Comment: then you should use custom `progressbar`

Comment: you give example of custom progress bar

Comment: user : sean is already gave you link follow that one..that may help you..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look through this link.

http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

The 2 arrow button can be design using a image button to increment or decrement the progressbar via e program.

Comment: how to done progress in white line and remain progress line in black as figure.